# Do you lose access to keyboard and mice when disabling USB from BIOS?

Tags: bios, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I think I know how to disable USB in bios but I am trying to figure out if I disable USB in bios and password protect bios, does that lock me out because now I can't use keyboard and mice?

Comment: If you don't have a [PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port) keyboard/mouse port, and you have disabled USB devices within BIOS, you would indeed be unable to use a USB keyboard/mouse in a case like that

Comment: to complement @Ramhound: you are locked out, until you open up the computer and perform a CMOS reset. This resets the BIOS to defaults, and usb is enabled again.

Comment: @LPChip – are you sure that USB ports (allowing keyboard access) are not temporarily enabled during POST even if disabled in BIOS settings, still allowing to enter BIOS setup using the keyboard? I am really interested whether someone really tested the lockout.

Comment: @miroxlav it is possible protection has been build in, but I've been locked out in the past with a similar case, so its definitely possible. I gained access by resetting the bios.

Comment: It pretty much assumes you disable it only because you have a PCI(e) USB host controller card and you connect your mouse and keyboard to that (or PS/2 ports, if any).

Comment: @everyone : I found 2 places where I can disable USB. One under Main -> BIOS level USB and second under Advanced -> South Cluster Configuration -> USB Configuration. Here you can disable individual USBs. First option clearly states if disabled then that will prevent keyboard from working. Second option I tested it also does the same thing.